# How to find string in another sheet and copy/paste data to current sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to construct a macro to find the same part name as I have highlighted in my "Tests" sheet in my "Part Catalog" sheet.

From here, I would like to copy the date when the part was manufactured (which is one column to the right of the part name) from the "Part Catalog" sheet, and paste it in a cell one column to the right of the part name in the "Tests" sheet.

I get an error saying that "Object doesn't support this property or method."

The code below is taken and slightly modified from this link: (http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=158840&p=578982#post578982). Previous attempts included me using for loops, but the majority of people seem to agree that the .find function works the best for things like this.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

```
Sub Get_Date()

    Dim Partname As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set sh = Sheets("Tests")
    Set ws = Sheets("Part Catalog")
    Partname = ActiveCell.Value

    ws.Cells.Find(Partname).Offset(0, 1).Copy
    sh.Cells.Find(Partname).Offset(0, 1).Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

For your follow on question:

Assumes you have the entire list of part names selected first:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim c, rng As Range

Set sh = Sheets("Tests")
Set ws = Sheets("Part Catalog")
Set rng = Selection


For Each c In rng
    ws.Cells.Find(c.Value).Offset(0, 1).Copy Destination:=c.Offset(0, 1)
Next c
```

This uses a loop to go through each part (cell) in your selection.